# PostGreSQL sent me this error message: "ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "corsi"". Can someone help me?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, error-handling, entity-relationship

PostGreSQL sent me this error message:

> "ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "corsi""

Can someone help me?

THOSE ARE THE TABLES:

```
CREATE TABLE Genitori (
CF varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
Nome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Cognome varchar(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Medici (
CF varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
Nome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Cognome varchar(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Qualifiche (
NomeQualifica varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Clienti (
NumTessera decimal(5, 0) PRIMARY KEY,
Nome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Cognome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
DataNascita date NOT NULL,
CFGenitore varchar(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Genitori (CF) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
NumCertificato decimal(5, 0),
CFMedico varchar(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Medici (CF) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
DataCertificato date NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Personale (
CF varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
Nome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Cognome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
TipoPersonale varchar(20) NOT NULL,
TipoAssunzione varchar(20),
Ferie varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Telefoni (
Numero decimal(10, 0) PRIMARY KEY,
Tipo varchar(10) NOT NULL,
PersonaProprietaria varchar(20) REFERENCES Personale (CF) ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE Piscine (
CodPiscina varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
Nome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Citta varchar(15) NOT NULL,
Cap decimal(7, 0) NOT NULL,
Via varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PeriodoApertura varchar(20) NOT NULL,
NumTelefono decimal(10, 0) NOT NULL REFERENCES Telefoni (Numero) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
UNIQUE(Nome, Citta, Cap, Via)
);

CREATE TABLE Corsi (
Livello varchar(3),
Tipo varchar(15), 
Piscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine (CodPiscina) ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
PRIMARY KEY (Livello, Tipo, Piscina)
);

CREATE TABLE Attiva (
CodPiscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine (CodPiscina) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
Livello varchar(3) REFERENCES Corsi (Livello),
Tipo varchar(15) REFERENCES Corsi (Tipo),
PRIMARY KEY (CodPiscina, Livello, Tipo)
); 

CREATE TABLE ImpieghiPassati (
CFDipendente varchar(20),
Piscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine (CodPiscina) ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
Fine date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CFDipendente, Piscina)
);

CREATE TABLE ImpieghiCorrenti (
CFDipendente varchar(20),
Piscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine (CodPiscina) ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
Inizio date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CFDipendente, Piscina)
);

CREATE TABLE Responsabili (
CF varchar (20) REFERENCES Personale (CF),
Nome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Cognome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CF)
);

CREATE TABLE Dirige (
CFResponsabile varchar(20) REFERENCES Responsabili (CF),
Piscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine (CodPiscina) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
Reperibilità varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(CFResponsabile, Piscina)
);

CREATE TABLE Sostituzioni (
Sostituente varchar(20) REFERENCES Personale (CF),
Sostituito varchar(20) REFERENCES Personale (CF),
DataInizio date NOT NULL,
DataFine date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Sostituente, Sostituito)
);

CREATE TABLE Vasche (
NumVasca decimal(2, 0) NOT NULL,
Piscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine (CodPiscina),
NumCorsie decimal(2,0) NOT NULL,
Tipologia varchar(15) NOT NULL,
Locazione varchar(10) NOT NULL,
InizioFruizione varchar(20) NOT NULL,
FineFruizione varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (NumVasca, Piscina)
);

CREATE TABLE Qualificati (
CFIstruttore varchar(20) REFERENCES Personale (CF),
NomeQualifica varchar(30) REFERENCES Qualifiche (NomeQualifica),
PRIMARY KEY (CFIstruttore, NomeQualifica)
);

CREATE TABLE Edizioni (
Orario varchar(11),
Giorno varchar(9),
LivelloCorso varchar(3) REFERENCES Corsi (Livello),
TipoCorso varchar(15) REFERENCES Corsi (Tipo),
Piscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine (CodPiscina),
NMax decimal(2, 0) NOT NULL,
NMin decimal(2,0) NOT NULL,
Corsia decimal (2, 0) NOT NULL,
CFIstruttore varchar(20) REFERENCES Personale (CF),
PRIMARY KEY (Orario, Giorno, LivelloCorso, TipoCorso, Piscina)
);

CREATE TABLE Iscritti (
Cliente decimal(5, 0) REFERENCES Clienti(NumTessera),
GiornoEd varchar(9) REFERENCES Edizioni (Giorno),
OrarioEd varchar(11) REFERENCES Edizioni (Orario),
LivelloCorso varchar(3) REFERENCES Corsi (Livello),
TipoCorso varchar(15) REFERENCES Corsi (Tipo),
Piscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine(CodPiscina),
PRIMARY KEY (Cliente, GiornoEd, OrarioEd, LivelloCorso, TipoCorso, Piscina)
);
```

EDITED CODE
|
|
|
|

```
CREATE TABLE Genitori (
CF varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
Nome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Cognome varchar(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Medici (
CF varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
Nome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Cognome varchar(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Qualifiche (
NomeQualifica varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Clienti (
NumTessera decimal(5, 0) PRIMARY KEY,
Nome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Cognome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
DataNascita date NOT NULL,
CFGenitore varchar(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Genitori (CF) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
NumCertificato decimal(5, 0),
CFMedico varchar(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Medici (CF) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
DataCertificato date NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Personale (
CF varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
Nome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Cognome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
TipoPersonale varchar(20) NOT NULL,
TipoAssunzione varchar(20),
Ferie varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Telefoni (
Numero decimal(10, 0) PRIMARY KEY,
Tipo varchar(10) NOT NULL,
PersonaProprietaria varchar(20) REFERENCES Personale (CF) ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE Piscine (
CodPiscina varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
Nome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Citta varchar(15) NOT NULL,
Cap decimal(7, 0) NOT NULL,
Via varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PeriodoApertura varchar(20) NOT NULL,
NumTelefono decimal(10, 0) NOT NULL REFERENCES Telefoni (Numero) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
UNIQUE(Nome, Citta, Cap, Via)
);

CREATE TABLE Corsi (
Livello varchar(3),
Tipo varchar(15), 
Piscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine (CodPiscina) ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
PRIMARY KEY (Livello, Tipo, Piscina)
);

CREATE TABLE Attiva (
CodPiscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine (CodPiscina) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
Livello varchar(3),
Tipo varchar(15),
PRIMARY KEY (CodPiscina, Livello, Tipo),
FOREIGN KEY (Livello, Tipo) REFERENCES Corsi(Livello, Tipo)
); 

CREATE TABLE ImpieghiPassati (
CFDipendente varchar(20),
Piscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine (CodPiscina) ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
Fine date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CFDipendente, Piscina)
);

CREATE TABLE ImpieghiCorrenti (
CFDipendente varchar(20),
Piscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine (CodPiscina) ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
Inizio date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CFDipendente, Piscina)
);

CREATE TABLE Responsabili (
CF varchar (20) REFERENCES Personale (CF),
Nome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Cognome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CF)
);

CREATE TABLE Dirige (
CFResponsabile varchar(20) REFERENCES Responsabili (CF),
Piscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine (CodPiscina) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
Reperibilità varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(CFResponsabile, Piscina)
);

CREATE TABLE Sostituzioni (
Sostituente varchar(20) REFERENCES Personale (CF),
Sostituito varchar(20) REFERENCES Personale (CF),
DataInizio date NOT NULL,
DataFine date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Sostituente, Sostituito)
);

CREATE TABLE Vasche (
NumVasca decimal(2, 0) NOT NULL,
Piscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine (CodPiscina),
NumCorsie decimal(2,0) NOT NULL,
Tipologia varchar(15) NOT NULL,
Locazione varchar(10) NOT NULL,
InizioFruizione varchar(20) NOT NULL,
FineFruizione varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (NumVasca, Piscina)
);

CREATE TABLE Qualificati (
CFIstruttore varchar(20) REFERENCES Personale (CF),
NomeQualifica varchar(30) REFERENCES Qualifiche (NomeQualifica),
PRIMARY KEY (CFIstruttore, NomeQualifica)
);

CREATE TABLE Edizioni (
Orario varchar(11),
Giorno varchar(9),
LivelloCorso varchar(3),
TipoCorso varchar(15),
Piscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine (CodPiscina),
NMax decimal(2, 0) NOT NULL,
NMin decimal(2,0) NOT NULL,
Corsia decimal (2, 0) NOT NULL,
CFIstruttore varchar(20) REFERENCES Personale (CF),
FOREIGN KEY (LivelloCorso, TipoCorso) REFERENCES Corsi (Livello, Tipo),
PRIMARY KEY (Orario, Giorno, LivelloCorso, TipoCorso, Piscina)
);

CREATE TABLE Iscritti (
Cliente decimal(5, 0) REFERENCES Clienti(NumTessera),
GiornoEd varchar(9),
OrarioEd varchar(11),
LivelloCorso varchar(3),
TipoCorso varchar(15),
Piscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine(CodPiscina),
FOREIGN KEY (LivelloCorso, TipoCorso) REFERENCES Corsi(Livello, Tipo),
FOREIGN KEY (GiornoEd, OrarioEd) REFERENCES Edizioni (Giorno, Orario),
PRIMARY KEY (Cliente, GiornoEd, OrarioEd, LivelloCorso, TipoCorso, Piscina)
);
```

Comment: Please, show your attempt to fix the problem or edit your question and ask what is your problem when you try to fix the error

Answer (score 1):

to be able to reference a column , that column should be a candidate key ( either Primary key or unique key. in your structure , you have a combined key so , fk should be a combined key as well:

```
CREATE TABLE Edizioni (
Orario varchar(11),
Giorno varchar(9),
LivelloCorso varchar(3) ,
TipoCorso varchar(15),
Piscina varchar(10) REFERENCES Piscine (CodPiscina),
NMax decimal(2, 0) NOT NULL,
NMin decimal(2,0) NOT NULL,
Corsia decimal (2, 0) NOT NULL,
CFIstruttore varchar(20) REFERENCES Personale (CF),
PRIMARY KEY (Orario, Giorno, LivelloCorso, TipoCorso, Piscina),
Foreign Key (LivelloCorso,TipoCorso) REFERENCES Corsi (Livello,Tipo)
);
```

the same for Iscritti table

Comment: I tried what you said but it gives me the same error... I'm editing the question so there's also the updated code.

Comment: @Andrea because Corsi (Livello,Tipo) columns are not unique , they are part of primary key but by themselves they are not unique . so you should either add Piscina column to that table or add a unique key on   (Livello,Tipo) in Corsi table. but overall seems like your database design has flaws.